# Json Assert Fails Laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, phpunit, laravel-5.5

I am making a flash cards app with laravel 5.5
So I am trying to make the first tests but I can't make it pass.

```html
Failed asserting that an array has the subset Array &0 (
    'data' => Array &1 (
        'id' => 2020
    )
).
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
-    [data] => Array
-        (
-            [id] => 2020
-        )
-

/Users/marcosantana/devel/cards/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/TestResponse.php:290
/Users/marcosantana/devel/cards/tests/Unit/CardTest.php:26

FAILURES!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 1, Failures: 1.
```

The test code:

```html
<?php

namespace Tests\Unit;

use Tests\TestCase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithFaker;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;
use App\User;
use App\Card;

class CardTest extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase;
    use DatabaseMigrations;


    public function testCardsResponds()
    {
        //$user = factory(\App\User::class)->create(['password' => "password"]);
        //$payload = ['email' => $user->email, 'password' => "password"];
        factory(\App\Card::class)->create(['id' => 2020]);//Creates a specific card
        $response = $this->json('GET', 'api/cards');
        $response->assertJson(['data' => ["id" => 2020]]);
/*
        $response
            ->assertStatus(200)
            ->assertSuccessful()
            ->assertJson(['{id}' => 2020]);
            // dd($response);

         */
    }
}
```

The routes/api.php

```html
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| is assigned the "api" middleware group. Enjoy building your API!
|
*/

Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

Route::get('/cards', function(Request $request) {
   return \App\Card::all();
});
```

The server output http://localhost:8000/api/cards

```html
[
  {
    id: 2020,
    tags: "{"lang": "st", "pictures": false}",
    front: "<html><head><title>Optio sit consequuntur vel         excepturi fuga eum amet.</title></head><body><form action="example.net" method="POST"><label for="username">ut</label><input type="text" id="username"><label for="password">excepturi</label><input type="password" id="password"></form><a href="example.org">Sunt ea quia molestias quod consequatur occaecati earum.</a></body></html>
    ",
    back: "<html><head><title>Et qui vel odit qui repellendus nihil architecto.</title></head><body><form action="example.net" method="POST"><label for="username">ratione</label><input type="text" id="username"><label for="password">iste</label><input type="password" id="password"></form><i>Quia dolor voluptas aut et rem natus ut provident sint enim ullam est.</i>Laboriosam voluptas in aut dignissimos accusamus cupiditate molestias vitae.</body></html>
    ",
    created_at: "2017-12-20 10:07:38",
    updated_at: "2017-12-20 10:07:38",
    deleted_at: null
  }
]
```

So it seems that is an obvious solution but I can not see it any help will be very useful. Surely it must be something easy but I am really swamped

Thank you!! do not be sorry. You were very helpful.
Actually I would like to expand a little my question. Now I am trying to validate the rest of the json but the "tags" (mysql json) field gives me error
I try this:

```html
$response
            ->assertStatus(200)
            ->assertSuccessful()
            ->assertJson([
                [
                    'id' => 2020,
                    'tags' => json_encode(array('lang' => 'mh', 'pictures' => 'false'))
                ]
            ]);
```

And I get this:

```html
Failed asserting that an array has the subset Array &0 (
    0 => Array &1 (
        'id' => 2020
        'tags' => '{"lang":"mh","pictures":"false"}'
    )
).
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
 Array
 (
     [0] => Array
         (
             [id] => 2020
-            [tags] => {"lang":"mh","pictures":"false"}
+            [tags] => {"lang": "mh", "pictures": "false"}
```

What are your thoughts on this ? Thank you again!
@MarcinNabialek

Comment: Maybe you could show us code of your tests? It would definitely help.

Comment: From the test output, it's clear that it's expecting `array('data' => array('id' => 2020))`, but getting nothing.

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek Thank you I forgot it

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 problems with your code:

- There is no `data` in your response and you pass `data` to `assertJson`
- `assertJson` method expects string and not array

In your case instead of:

```
 $response->assertJson(['data' => ["id" => 2020]]);
```

you should rather use:

```
 $response->seeJsonSubset([["id" => 2020]]);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but it does not seem to work:
BadMethodCallException: Method seeJsonSubset does not exist.
BTW all methods with seeJson* don't work and in the 5.5 documentation they do not use them. @MarcinNabialek

Comment: @MarcoSantana Sorry for that. I had in my Laravel 5.5 also browser-kit testing library installed and gave you method from browser-kit instead of for pure Laravel 5.5 install

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```html
 $response->seeJsonSubset([["id" => 2020]]);
```

I just needed to use:

```html
$response
           /* ->assertStatus(200)
            ->assertSuccessful()*/
            ->assertJson([["id" => 2020]]);
```

And we get:

```html
PHPUnit 6.5.4 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

....                                                                4 / 4 (100%)

Time: 900 ms, Memory: 22.00MB

OK (4 tests, 6 assertions)
```

Thank you guys you lead me in the right direction.