# PHP Unit test assertJSON(

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

When unit testing a JSON response I am using assertJson(...)

```
assertJson([
                $booking1->only(['user_id', 'service_id','start', 'end']), 
                $booking2->only(['user_id', 'service_id','start', 'end']), 
                $booking3->only(['user_id', 'service_id','start', 'end']), 
                $booking4->only(['user_id', 'service_id','start', 'end']),
            ]);
```

My failure message is:

```
Failed asserting that an array has the subset Array &0 (
0 => Array &1 (
    'user_id' => 25
    'service_id' => 16
    'start' => '2019-12-02 09:41:58'
    'end' => '2019-12-02 09:56:58'       
)
1 => Array &2 (
    'user_id' => 25
    'service_id' => 16
    'start' => '2019-12-02 10:26:58'
    'end' => '2019-12-02 10:36:58'        
)
2 => Array &3 (
    'user_id' => 26
    'service_id' => 16
    'start' => '2019-12-02 09:41:58'
    'end' => '2019-12-02 09:56:58'        
)
3 => Array &4 (
    'user_id' => 26
    'service_id' => 16
    'start' => '2019-12-02 10:26:58'
    'end' => '2019-12-02 10:36:58'        
)
).
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
 array (
-  0 =>
-  array (
-    'user_id' => 25,
-    'service_id' => 16,
-    'start' => '2019-12-02 09:41:58',
-    'end' => '2019-12-02 09:56:58',
-  ),
-  1 =>
-  array (
-    'user_id' => 25,
-    'service_id' => 16,
-    'start' => '2019-12-02 10:26:58',
-    'end' => '2019-12-02 10:36:58',
-  ),
-  2 =>
-  array (
-    'user_id' => 26,
-    'service_id' => 16,
-    'start' => '2019-12-02 09:41:58',
-    'end' => '2019-12-02 09:56:58',
-  ),
-  3 =>
-  array (
-    'user_id' => 26,
-    'service_id' => 16,
-    'start' => '2019-12-02 10:26:58',
-    'end' => '2019-12-02 10:36:58',
-  ),
 )
```

There are a few differences here "Array &0 ( vs array (" Other than that the data look to be the same.

Can anyone tell me what the significance of these differences are? Or am I missing something else here as well?

Thanks

Comment: How are you calling the array in `assertJson(...)`? Can reveal the `...`?

Comment: I have updated the question to include the way I am calling the assertJson.

Comment: I'm hitting a blank too. Sorry. There is a similar situation here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47910741/json-assert-fails-laravel-5-5  Can you maybe check if passing one value works? As in, `assertJson([['user_id' => 25]])` like the second answer there?

Comment: are $bookings Collections? use toArray() after using only()

Answer (score 0):

This issue was that I am interpreting the error message wrong - The +++ Actual is misleading me by making me think that was the "Actual" response. I didn't notice the part just before the "Failed" statement that was saying:

```
within response JSON:

[[]]
```

So the response is empty and the error message was telling me, presumably that the +++ Actual was what was additional to what I was looking for?

So there is no actual error - just my interpretation of the response is wrong.

Thanks all for looking at this though!